# Widget not responding on tapping

Tags: android

I am trying to create a simple widget. I wanted that, when touchet, to show a toast. But it does not show anything. I don't know where I'm wrong, it looks quite well(maybe i have forgotten something i didn't notice).

Code:
static String clAc = "CLICKED";

```
static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, LocationWidget.class);
    intent.setAction(clAc);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, intent,0);

    Paper.init(context);

    String title = Paper.book().read("content");

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.location_widget);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, title);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.layout_wrapper, pendingIntent);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }

}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if(intent.getAction().contentEquals(clAc))
        Toast.makeText(context, "clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Is onReceive called? Make sure the view id is correct.

Comment: all the view ids are correct, because it takes the initial values, but it does not react when tapped

Comment: Put a log on the onReceive method to see if it's called.

Comment: should I put something in the onEnabled method?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update not each `appWidgetId`, but all `appWidgetIds` with your logic.